# Get current loaded language translation in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I want to know how to get the current loaded language translation in Odoo using python code.

For example,  I'd like to determine if the loaded translation language is in Japanese.

Comment: @Markus This question seems complete to me as someone who was famailiar with openerp 6 but not so much the newer code.  There's a time when given this question I could have answered it off the top of my head.  I've forgotten too much, but I think the question is clear and sufficient to people with necessary subject matter experience.

Comment: Fair enough. I removed my comment and upvoted the question. Thanks for clarifying it. For me it seemed rather incomplete, but I misguessed it. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you wanted to get the language of the loaded translation in odoo.
I have also encountered this.

Use this

```
request.env.lang
```

Example:`current_lang = request.env.lang`

If the loaded language is in Japanese, the output is ja_JP.

Hope this helps!